# How can I get the values submitted from a JSP in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I am using Liferay Portal 6 version. 
How can I get the UserName and Password values with in the same page?

```jsp
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@page import="javax.portlet.RenderRequest"%>
<portlet:defineObjects />

This is the <b>Kiran</b> portlet.

<form>
  <p><b>UserName:</b> <input type="text" name="UserName" size="10"></p>
  <p><b>Password:</b> &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="Password" name="Password" 
size="10"></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"><input type=
"reset" value="Reset" name="reset"></p><hr><hr>
</form>


<%

// here


%>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if its submitting the values correctly as your form has no target and is not refering to a portlet action url.

This [tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/jbportal/v2.4/reference-guide/en/html/tutorials.html) shows some basic usage and parameter retrieval. Check the JSP portlet section. You should be able to access the request object in your jsp as well.

I wouldn't start writing JSP portlets. Its quite outdated nowadays. Check [Spring Portlet MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/portlet.html) or even consider JSF.

Comment: I agree with Udo, you should be using wither Spring Portlet MVC or Liferay's MVCPortlet class.

Answer (score 1):

In a portal/portlet all identifiers must be properly namespaced - you never know what other content ends up on the same html document with you. Thus a form control should rather read:

```
<input type="text" name="<portlet:namespace/>user" .../>
```

in order to be able to retrieve the parameter as "user" from the request.

If, in Liferay 6, you use the AlloyUI taglibs, a lot of this namespacing is done automatically for you.

Also, you should add the portlet action URL as Udo Held suggests:

```
<form action="<portlet:actionURL/>">
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to get ? Do you want to get the username and password in some other .java file or .jsp file ?? Or do you want to get the username and password once a user logs in ?

If you are trying to get user details set in present jsp page in some other .java or .jsp, then simply use the PortletSession.
**Eg: From jsp**

```java
PortletSession portletSession = actionRequest.getPortletSession();       
portletSession.setAttribute("liferayUserMap", liferayUserMap,PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

**From .java/.jsp**

```java
PortletSession portletSession = actionRequest.getPortletSession();
portletSession.getAttribute("liferayUserMap",PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

By doing so, you can share the data among different files in different portlets too.

For case 2: If you are trying to get the user details, simply do the following:

```java
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
themeDisplay.getUser();
```

I hope you are following the portlet structures while coding, otherwise the above mentioned code wouldn't work. Since you have to point to some action class, in the **'struts-config'** and **'tiles-def'**