# Retrieving the Article Id from the Web Content Display portlet

Tags: liferay

I have a Web Content Portlet and another one (I'm developing) in the same layout.
The Liferay built-in Web Content portlet displays an article.

Is there a way to reach the **article id** from my portlet?

(I'm developing my portlet with Struts)

Answer (score 0):

You can share data between two different portlets by setting it in session. Set the article ID by editing the portlet code (of 1st portlet), set it in the session and retrieve it in you portlet. 
[>>Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463249/how-can-i-get-the-values-submitted-from-a-jsp-in-liferay/8472339#8472339)

Comment: it doesn't answer to my question.

Comment: From the web content portlet which you are having, put the article id in the session(inter portlet communication). From your portlet, try to read the val from the session.